# perl: added hash entry in a subroutine is lost

Tags: perl, hash, reference, subroutine

Why is the hash empty on the second call of printHash?

```
my %hash = ();
addToHash(\%hash);
printHash(\%hash);

sub addToHash {
  my %hash = %{$_[0]};
  $hash{"test"} = "test";
  printHash(\%hash);
} 

sub printHash {
  print "printHash: \n";
  my %hash = %{$_[0]};
  foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
      print "key: $key, value: $hash{$key}\n";      
  }
}
```

Output:

printHash:

key: test, value: test

printHash:

Answer (score 7):

In

```
sub addToHash {
  my %hash = %{$_[0]};
  $hash{"test"} = "test";
  printHash(\%hash);
}
```

`my %hash` creates a *new hash* into which you *copy* the hash referenced by the argument. You want

```
sub addToHash {
  my $hr = $_[0];
  $hr->{"test"} = "test";
  printHash($hr);
}
```

in order to modify the original hash.

Comment: `$_[0]->{"test"} = "test";`? Hardly seems worth the while to create a new variable for it.

Comment: For real use, no. For comparison to the original, I thought it was illustrative.

Answer (score 5):

Because the `addToHash` function is adding a key-value pair to a *copy* of the first `%hash` variable.

```
my %hash = %{$_[0]}
```

dereferences the hash reference in `$_[0]` but the assignment to `my %hash` creates a new copy of the hash's contents. If you want `addToHash` to affect the input hash reference, you still need to work with it as a hash reference:

```
sub addToHash {
    my $hashref = $_[0];
    $hashref->{"test"} = "test";
    printHash( $hashref );
}
```

---

Try this exercise to get a sense of the difference between using hashes and references to hashes.

```
%a = (foo => "bar");       # hash
$b = { foo => "bar" };     # reference to hash

%c = %a;                   # new copy of a hash
$c{"foo"} = "baz";         # changes the copy of %a, but not %a
print $a{"foo"};           # still outputs "bar"

$d = $b;                   # $d is reference to same hash that $b points to
$d->{"foo"} = "baz";       # changes $b
print $b->{"foo"};         # now outputs "baz"

$e = \%a;                  # $e is a reference to hash %a
$e->{"foo"} = "baz";       # changes %a
print $a{"foo"};           # now outputs "baz"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have local `%hash` in your subrutine and so you are not changing the one in main-scope.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use the hash *alias* (in your case, `$_[0]`) directly.